# kernel parameter for limiting total ram usage?

Tags: kernel, ram

I run Kubuntu 20.04, stock kernel on a Lenovo X201i. I have 4G of ram and get frequent visits by the oom-killer. A co-worker gave me two 8G SO-DIMMs. Problem is, the X201i detects 16GB but can only use 8GB due to memory controller not supporting more ram. So, when the X201i starts using more mem, probably reaching the 8GB border, it crashes. Buying 2x4GB SO-DIMM for a 10 year old machine seems not too economical as the mem still costs aroung 40-50 Euros. Is it possible to prevent the usage of the 'upper' 8GB? I tried mem=8GB and memmap=08GB@00GB without success. I either get funny colors or no boot at all.

dmidecode yields this

```
dmidecode 3.2

Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs. SMBIOS 2.6 present.

Handle 0x0007, DMI type 5, 20 bytes Memory Controller Information Error Detecting Method: None Error Correcting Capabilities: None Supported Interleave: One-way Interleave Current Interleave: One-way Interleave Maximum Memory Module Size: 4096 MB Maximum Total Memory Size: 8192 MB Supported Speeds: Other Supported Memory Types: DIMM SDRAM Memory Module Voltage: 2.9 V Associated Memory Slots: 2 0x0008 0x0009 Enabled Error Correcting Capabilities: Unknown

Handle 0x0008, DMI type 6, 12 bytes Memory Module Information Socket Designation: DIMM Slot 1 Bank Connections: 0 1 Current Speed: 43 ns Type: DIMM SDRAM Installed Size: 8192 MB (Double-bank Connection) Enabled Size: 8192 MB (Double-bank Connection) Error Status: OK

Handle 0x0009, DMI type 6, 12 bytes Memory Module Information Socket Designation: DIMM Slot 2 Bank Connections: 2 3 Current Speed: 43 ns Type: DIMM SDRAM Installed Size: 8192 MB (Double-bank Connection) Enabled Size: 8192 MB (Double-bank Connection) Error Status: OK

Handle 0x002A, DMI type 16, 15 bytes Physical Memory Array Location: System Board Or Motherboard Use: System Memory Error Correction Type: None Maximum Capacity: 8 GB Error Information Handle: Not Provided Number Of Devices: 2

Handle 0x002B, DMI type 17, 28 bytes Memory Device Array Handle: 0x002A Error Information Handle: No Error Total Width: 64 bits Data Width: 64 bits Size: 8192 MB Form Factor: SODIMM Set: None Locator: DIMM 1 Bank Locator: Bank 0/1 Type: DDR3 Type Detail: Synchronous Speed: 1600 MT/s Manufacturer: 0198
Serial Number: 4B057A41
Asset Tag: 1936 Part Number: KHX1600C9S3L/8G
Rank: Unknown

Handle 0x002C, DMI type 17, 28 bytes Memory Device Array Handle: 0x002A Error Information Handle: No Error Total Width: 64 bits Data Width: 64 bits Size: 8192 MB Form Factor: SODIMM Set: None Locator: DIMM 2 Bank Locator: Bank 2/3 Type: DDR3 Type Detail: Synchronous Speed: 1600 MT/s Manufacturer: 0198
Serial Number: 4C05AD41
Asset Tag: 1936 Part Number: KHX1600C9S3L/8G
Rank: Unknown
```

uname is

```
Linux arno-ThinkPad-X201 5.4.0-29-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 29 14:32:27 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Wouldn't using only one of the SO-DIMMs solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

From top of my head (so you have to read up on it).
You have to parse a kernel parameter.

If you er using grub bootloader, this can be done by (if you have a boot menu) parsing the kernel parameter tempoaraly to the kernel.

To make it permanent edit /etc/default/grub (<-conf or something like that) and run update-grub.

I think that the parameter to limit mem is this simple:

mem=128M

I recommend that you test first before making it permanet.
Something to consider:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/ramoops.html

Comment: Oh just realized that you already tried the mem parameter. Maybe it can't handle 8G try using 8192M

Answer (score 0):

I solved it the 'old fashioned' way. Upgraded to a X220 with 8GB. Installed the 8GB in the X201 and gave it to my friend. Run the X220 with the 16GB which did not work in the X201...
Greetings, Arno